# Calculating percentage of a particular value?

Tags: percentage, databricks

So, I have a table where a bunch of people took multiple surveys. Each survey had a rating out of 10. I need to calculate the average rating per survey and number of 10s (which I've already done). Now I need to find the percentage of 10s

Below is the code I have currently:

```
SELECT person, 
survey, 
AVG(rating), 
COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 10 THEN 1 END) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY person, survey
```

I have a general of idea of how to calculate percentages, but struggling on how to calculate the percentage of just the 10's. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT rating, COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 10 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) FROM table 
GROUP BY rating;
```

Did you mean this?